# Is there any way to make such design in Flutter

Tags: flutter-layout

As shown in the below Image.
I want an image at the bottom of the stack, a container above it and a transparent text widget above them. I'm unable to figure out any solution, please help!

[image]

Comment: I later want to add parallax effect to it, that's why I'm not using image editor here to make the desired text

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution, works like a charm

```
import 'dart:typed_data';
import 'dart:ui' as ui;
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/rendering.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';

class Penumbra extends StatefulWidget {
 Penumbra({Key key}) : super(key: key);

 @override
 _PenumbraState createState() => _PenumbraState();
}

class _PenumbraState extends State<Penumbra> {
 @override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  Size size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;

return Scaffold(
    body: Stack(
  children: [
    Row(
      children: [
        Container(
          width: size.width / 2,
          height: double.maxFinite,
          color: Color(0xff181818),
        ),
        Container(
          width: size.width / 2,
          height: double.maxFinite,
          color: Colors.white,
        )
      ],
    ),
    SingleChildScrollView(
      child: Column(
        children: [
          Container(
            height: size.height,
          ),
          ImageShaderWidget(),
          Container(
            height: size.height,
          ),
        ],
      ),
    ),
  ],
));
}
}


class ImageShaderWidget extends StatelessWidget {
 @override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) => Container(
    child: FutureBuilder<TextStyle>(
      future: loadImage(
          TextStyle(fontSize: 104.0, fontWeight: FontWeight.w900)),
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
          return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
        } else {
          return Text(
            "Penumbra",
            style: snapshot.data,
          );
        }
      },
    ),
  );

  Future<TextStyle> loadImage(TextStyle textStyle) async {
   final imageBytes = await rootBundle.load('../assets/images/background.jpg');
   ui.Image img = await decodeImageFromList(imageBytes.buffer.asUint8List());
   Float64List matrix4 = new Matrix4.identity().storage;
   return textStyle.copyWith(
    foreground: Paint()
      ..shader =
          ImageShader(img, TileMode.mirror, TileMode.mirror, matrix4));
  }
 }
```